# hickle NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

please explain to me why this error getting for me. I have install python 3.5 in ubuntu

```html
import os
import hickle as hkl
import numpy as np
array_obj = np.ones(32768, dtype='float32')
hkl.dump(array_obj, 'test.hkl', mode='w')
```

the result is

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\hickle.py", line 308, in dump
    h5f = file_opener(file_obj, mode, track_times)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\hickle.py", line 148, in file_opener
    if isinstance(f, file):
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Comment: `file()` is not supported in Python 3.
you should install Python 2.7 and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hickle doesn't support Python3 (it uses file() function not supported in Python3), but you can find [modified version](https://github.com/karandwivedi42/hickle) on GitHub, or just use Python2.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the main developers of hickle: 3 years ago, it indeed did not support Python 3 yet.
Nowadays on the other hand, it works just fine (and, in fact, has dropped support for Python 2.7 by now).