# Provided argument 'file_obj' does not appear to be a valid hickle file (Hickle in python version 3.6.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hdf5

I am trying to open hickle files in python version 3.6.9, but I get the following error :

`ValueError: Provided argument 'file_obj' does not appear to be a valid hickle file! (HDF5-file attribute 'CLASS' does not have value 'hickle'!)`

I am a beginer in python and I tried to install different Hickle versions, however, I am unable to solve this problem. I tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276174/hickle-nameerror-name-file-is-not-defined), but doesen't work. Can someone suggest a solution to this?. Is it due to the reason that my hickle files were written using python 2.7.17 ?.

Comment: Did you already try asking on the official `hickle` pages?

Answer (score 0):

I removed support for Python 2.7 in hickle v4, which was released half-way through 2020.
However, hickle v4 should be capable of reading any file that was created in Python 2.7 with hickle v3.
If not, I would suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/telegraphic/hickle/issues and providing all the details, such that I can take a look at the problem.